# Change legend position of ng-charts (using angular2)

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

How do I change the position of the legend (that by default appears on top of the chart)? I'm using `ng-charts`, and I'm trying to change the position according to the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration), but it does not seem to be working.

[image: chart]

The template contains this:

```
<canvas baseChart
  [datasets]="datasets"
  [labels]="labels"
  [chartType]="type"
  [colors]="colors"
  [legend]="legend"
  [position]="position">
</canvas>
```

And the component variables are:

```
labels: string[] = [ 'EMI', 'Food', 'Fuel', 'bike' ];
type: string = 'doughnut';
legend: boolean = true;
position: string = 'left';
colors: Color[] = [{}];

datasets: any[] = [{
  data: [ 3350, 5450, 4100, 1000 ],
  backgroundColor: [
    "#FF6384",
    "#36A2EB",
    "#FFCE56"
  ],
  hoverBackgroundColor: [
    "#FF6384",
    "#36A2EB",
    "#FFCE56"
  ]
}];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart JS, ng2-Charts - How to make the label to the right of pie chart instead on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504543/chart-js-ng2-charts-how-to-make-the-label-to-the-right-of-pie-chart-instead-o)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As per the [readme](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts#properties) of `ng2-charts`, you can use `options` to change any properties not exposed by `ng2-charts` itself.

Add `[options]="options"` to your template, and an `options` variable to your component:

```
private options: any = {
  legend: { position: 'left' }
}
```

Comment: This no longer works in 2022 with ng-charts version 4.0.1. Setting is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

With ng-charts version 4.0.1. it's:

```
private options: any = {
  plugins: { legend: { position: 'left' } }
}
```