# Chart JS, ng2-Charts - How to make the label to the right of pie chart instead on top?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-material, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using the chart js https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js  and **ng2-charts** https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts , to render a doughnut chart.

[image: doughnut chart]

But, I want the label to appear on the right of the **doughnut chart**, any idea on how do I do that?

```
  public monthStatsLabel: Label[] = ['Total days', 'Present', 'Leave'];
  public monthStatsData: MultiDataSet = [
    [31,28,2]
  ];
  public monthStatsType: string = 'doughnut';
  public chartClicked({ event, active }: { event: MouseEvent, active: {}[] }): void {
    console.log(event, active);
  }
```

```
<canvas baseChart
                    [data]="monthStatsData"
                    [labels]="monthStatsLabel"
                    [chartType]="monthStatsType"
                    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, import **ChartOptions** object in your `component.ts`:

```
import { ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
```

Create a new variable with it in your `component.ts`:

```
public options: ChartOptions = {
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'right'  // <=========== change this to the position you like.
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: "Employee Details",
  }
  // ... and so on. see below about options
}
```

Now, in your `component.html`, add the `options` variable to `<canvas>`:

```
<canvas baseChart
                [data]="monthStatsData"
                [labels]="monthStatsLabel"
                [chartType]="monthStatsType"
                [options]="options" 
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

[Read more about ng2-chart options and customization here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1345/customization-with-ng2-charts-an-easy-way-to-visualize-data)

Comment: No problem, happy coding :))

Comment: This no longer works in 2022 with ng-charts version 4.0.1. You cannot declare ChartOptions without a generic type specifier. And setting `ChartOptions<'pie'>` does not allow `legend` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know anything about ng2-Charts, but you probably need to add something

```
[options] = "chartOptions"
```

to your basechart and

```
  public chartOptions: legend = {
    position: 'right'
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

With latest `ng2-charts` (v4.0.1) and `chart.js`, you need to use the following code:

```
public options: ChartOptions<'pie'> = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'doughnut'
    },
  }
};
```

Notice `legend` is under `plugins`. This can be found in the official documentation:

- https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

Specifically, this part:

> Namespace: options.plugins.legend, the global options for the chart legend is defined in Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.

Don't forget to update the template:

```
<canvas baseChart
        ...
        [options]="options">
</canvas>
```

I just got it working with Angular 14.